# How can set color to selectonemenu row

Tags: primefaces

how can I set color to p:selectOneMenu row, 
I have a selectOneMenu with a client list. Canceled Customers want the row is red background color.

```
     <p:selectOneMenu id="listaClientesmodi" value="#{clientesMB.selectedEmpClienteCancelarContrato}" converter="clientesConverter"  panelStyle="width:500px"  
                                 effect="fade" var="p" style="width:500px"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">  

                    <f:selectItems value="#{comunMB.itemsClientes}"/>  

                    <p:column>  
                        #{p.codigo} - #{p.nombre}  
                    </p:column>  
                    <f:ajax execute="@this"  listener="#{clientesMB.cargarContratosClienteSelected}"  render=":form2:panelDetalles :form2:panelEditContrato" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all rows to be painted:

```
.ui-selectonemenu-item {
    background-color: aqua!important;
}
```

But if you want to make conditional painting; I found a bit complicated solution there can be another and much simpler solutions of course.

To be able to apply my solution you need a field which is the size of your clients those shown in the `p:selectOneMenu`. But more important thing you need to add text like `canceled` or whatever which will say to js function that item is need to be painted.

If `comunMB.itemsClientes` is shown in the `p:selectOneMenu` concatenate "canceled" string to canceled clients. Because the canceled clients need to be differentiated from others. And my solution requires it sorry for that was best I can do.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; '#{clientesMB.size}'; i++) {
        if($(".ui-selectonemenu-items li:nth-child("+i+")").text().indexOf("Canceled") != -1) {
            $(".ui-selectonemenu-items li:nth-child("+i+")").css({"background-color":"#ff1315"});
        }
    }
});
```

So; `p:selectOneMenu` generates a html list. If you investigate it from browsers developer settings, it's looking like:

```
<ul class="ui-selectonemenu-items">
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
</ul>
```

So function firstly selects the element from it's CSS class which is named as `ui-selectonemenu-items` and looks for it's children, and for each child it is looking for they are canceled or not.

`indexOf` function returns -1 when item doesn't include string of "canceled" so we are finding the elements which has "canceled" text and change their background color, that's it.

Comment: Or if you know the exact number of your clients, give that number instead `'#{clientesMB.size}'`